Two questions on ring proofs
I am learning about rings and subrings, and I am having some trouble with two particular proofs.
First, let $R$ be a ring with unity and with at least two elements. Show the additive identity is not equal to the multiplicative identity. I tried to assume they were the same and reach a contradiction, but I am having trouble.
So assume $u \in R$ is both the additive and multiplicative identity. Given $a \in R$, we have $a + u = a$ and $au = ua = a$. This means $a + u = au$ and $au + u = a$. Thus $(a+u) + u = a + 2u =  a + u$, meaning $2u = u$. And now I don't know what to do.
Second, given a commutative ring $R$, let $N(R)$ be the set of all $a \in R$ such that $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$. Show $N(R)$ is a subring of $R$.
So if $a^n=0$ and $b^m=0$, then $(ab)^n$ = ${a^n}{b^n}$ = $(0)b^n = 0$, meaning $N(R)$ is closed under multiplication. I'm not sure this is right, because I don't know if we can distribute exponents like this in a ring. And how to show $a-b \in N(R)$? I tried to use the binomial theorem, but got nowhere.

(1) if $0=1$ then $0=0a=1a=a$ for all $a\in R$, so $R$ has only one element; (2) if $R$ is commutative, then $(ab)^n=ababab\dots ab=a^nb^n$

For the second problem, there is an issue. Do you assume $R$ has an identity? If you do, think of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (the ring of residues $\mod 4$) with usual addition and multiplication. Then it is easy to see that $N(R)={0,2}$, which is not a ring.

Hi! Please don't ask disparate questions in a single post. Your second question is definitely already answered on the site, and I suspect the first one is too.

For the first one, prove by contrapositive: If the additive identity is equal to the multiplicative identity, then there is exactly one element in the ring $R$.
$proof$:Since $1_R=0,$ for any $r\in R$, we have $r=r1_R=r0=0,$ which means $R=\{0\}.$
Second part:
$Sketch \ of\ proof$: First, this set is not empty since $0\in N(R).$If $a,b\in N(R)$(i.e $a^n=b^m=0$), then $a+b\in R.$ (Binomial Theorem) $(a+b)^{mn}=a^{mn}+\sum_{k=1}^{mn-1}\binom{mn}{k}a^{k}b^{mn-k}+b^{mn}$
Hint:$b^{mn-k}=b^{n}b^{mn-k-n}=0$ and $a^{k}=a^{m}a^{k-m}=0$ if $k\geq m.$
Finally, if $a\in N(R),$ it's clear that $-a\in N(R).$
